# Was there any changes made for this Functionality in Salesforce winter 17 release?

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, detail-page, winter17

I had a Custom Link created through Apex and it will display in the Account detail page. Previously i could copy the Link and use it. However after Winter 17 release I could not do it.

Please find the image below.
[image]

Please Advise

Comment: The one thing I'll note is that's an http instead of https url you're calling out to which by definition is insecure. That could be the cause of your issue.

Comment: @crmprogdev I have tried updating the http to https. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @SamuelRobert In what way is this not working? Is the link not returning the expected result? Does it return an error message? What is behind the link? Is it a Visualforce page?

Comment: @DanielBallinger It will take us to the Visual force page. Usually we will trigger email to our customers. But internally our client used to copy the link and paste in the browser for testing it. However after winter 17 release we were unable to copy the link.

Comment: @SamuelRobert You can't copy the link the the clipboard? What mechanism are you using to copy the link? Is it something in JavaScript or the native OS functionality?